# Cannot solve an AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'ROOT_URLCONF' conundrum after doing a lot of research

Tags: python, django

I have an issue that I been trying to solve for a while. I am creating my first Django app by following instructions from a site. I am currently working on accessing the admin page, but it has not been working. In addition, I am getting an error of "A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator" when I run the local server. This was not happening before I tried access the django admin page.
The error callback's last line is:

```
AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'ROOT_URLCONF'
```

The full callback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
File "/home/username/Desktop/djangoajax/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 67, in __call__
return self.application(environ, start_response)
File "/home/username/Desktop/djangoajax/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 241, in __call__
response = self.get_response(request)
File "/home/username/Desktop/djangoajax/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 82, in get_response
urlconf = settings.ROOT_URLCONF
File "/home/username/Desktop/djangoajax/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 185, in inner
return func(self._wrapped, *args)
AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'ROOT_URLCONF'
```

The manage.py is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

The settings.py is:

```
# Django settings for mysite project.
import os
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from mysite import views

DIRNAME = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    ('My Name', 'email@mysite.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': '',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# In a Windows environment this must be set to your system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/New_York'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = ''

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(DIRNAME, 'static/')

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    #'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = 'xan1@gt5(i6uuf8gw)^440-0@0x)s5dgr9-3=#wnczlk)t%$mm'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    #'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'

import os.path
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
         os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates"),
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}

if settings.DEBUG:
        urlpatterns += patterns('django.clock_skew.static',
            (r'^%s(?P<path>.*)$' % (settings.MEDIA.URL[1:],), 'serve', {
                'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
                'show_indexes': True}),)

django.contrib.admin.site.register(directory.models.Entity)
```

Admin.py is as follows:

```
import django.contrib.admin
import directory.models

django.contrib.admin.autodiscover()
django.contrib.admin.site.register(directory.models.Entity)
django.contrib.admin.site.register(directory.models.Location)
```

I have really been trying to solve this on my own and get the local server running error-free, but at this point I realize that I may need some help. I would appreciate any solutions that you can offer me. I am using django 1.4.1 and python 2.7.3. I'm using the `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080` command to start the server.

Many thanks...

Answer (score 7):

Yuck. You're doing all sorts of things in settings.py that should not be done there. You're importing urls and adding to them, and importing the admin and registering a model. Both of these actions rely on settings already being set up, so it's not surprising Django is getting confused.

Remove all those imports (except `os`), and move the URL modification to urls.py and the admin registration to the relevant admin.py.

Comment: Thanks for the help Daniel, that sorted it out : )