# setting has no attribute ROOT_URLCONF error while running app with virtualenv

Tags: django, settings

I'm getting an error while making a request to Django devserver (it is running in virtual environment dj_venv):

```
[19/Jul/2016 11:32:40] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 59
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/home/daria/venvs/dj_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 67, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/daria/venvs/dj_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 241, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/home/daria/venvs/dj_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 82, in get_response
    urlconf = settings.ROOT_URLCONF
  File "/home/daria/venvs/dj_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 185, in inner
    return func(self._wrapped, *args)
AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'ROOT_URLCONF'
```

The weird thing is that when I start server and don't make any request, I don't get any errors:

> daria@daria:~/cms.media$ . ../venvs/dj_venv/bin/activate
>
> (dj_venv) daria@daria:~/cms.media$ python manage.py runserver Validating
>   models...
>
> 0 errors found Django version 1.4.11, using settings 'apps.settings'
>   Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/ Quit the
>   server with CONTROL-C.

But after the first request I get an AttributeError as presented above.

I understand that this error is thrown because my settings object has no attribute 'ROOT_URLCONF', but I have defined it in settings.py and in global_settings.py of my virtual environment. I also looked at these articles:

1) Official docs ([ROOT_URLCONF option](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request) and [how Django processes a request](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request))

2) Related topics:

- [resolved by removing excessive early imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14015234/cannot-solve-an-attributeerror-settings-object-has-no-attribute-root-urlconf)
- [resolved by adding ROOT_URLCONF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12839213/attributeerror-settings-object-has-no-attribute-root-urlconf)

And I checked these points:

1) DJANGO_SETTING_MODULE is defined in manage.py (points to apps.settings)

2) ROOT_URLCONF is defined in settings.py (points to outer urls.py in apps folder)

3) DJANGO_SETTING_MODULE and ROOT_URLCONF added to PyCharm's Run > Edit Configuration > Environment variables

There is Environment variables:

```
DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE=1
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=apps.settings
PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
ROOT_URLCONF=urls
```

There is my project structure:

```
.
├── apps
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── wsgi.py
│   └── webapp
│       ├── context_processors.py
│       ├── defaults.py
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── models.py
│       ├── templates
│       │   └── ...
│       ├── urls.py
│       └── views.py
├── manage.py
└── ...
```

Also setting.py wich defines ROOT_URLCONF:

```
import os
import sys
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_noop as _
from django import template

DEBUG = True
# turn off for the perfomance in the production server
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

#USE_TZ = False
#TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Moscow'

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True


############
# SPICY App

APP_VERSION = '2.0'
AJAX_API_VERSION = '1.0'

# deprecated
MESSAGES = {'success': _('Changes were successfully saved.'),
            'error': _('Please, correct the errors below.')}

APP_SOURCE_PATH = 'apps/'
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath('.')
ADDITIONAL_PYTHON_PATH = [
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, APP_SOURCE_PATH),
]

############
# SITESKIN & STATIC
SITE_ID = 1
USE_CUSTOM_ADMIN = True
# deprecated
SITESKIN = ''
AJAX_ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN = '*.localhost'
CACHE_PREFIX = '%s-' % SITESKIN
CACHE_BACKEND = 'locmem://'

###################
# PROFILE

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGIN_URL = '/signin/'
REGISTRATION_OPEN = True
SECRET_KEY = 'lalala'
LOGIN_URL = '/signin/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'spicy.core.profile.auth_backends.CustomUserModelBackend',
)
USE_CAPTCHA = False
USE_FEEDBACK_CAPTCHA = False
CAPTCHA_CHALLENGE_FUNCT = 'captcha.helpers.math_challenge'
CAPTCHA_NOISE_FUNCTIONS = ()
#('captcha.helpers.noise_arcs','captcha.helpers.noise_dots',)

...

###############
## DJANGO

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@domain.com'),
)
MANAGERS = ADMINS

CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
        }
}
#CACHE_BACKEND = 'memcached://127.0.0.1:11311/'#'locmem:///'
CACHE_TIMEOUT = 1*60 # seconds

SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.cached_db"
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True
#SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = ''

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
THEMES_PATH = os.path.abspath('..')

try:
    from config import *
except ImportError, msg:
    raise ImportError, 'Using default config settings, check "config" directory.\n'

for _path in ADDITIONAL_PYTHON_PATH:
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(_path))

## deprecated
# while SITESKIN exists

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.abspath('../static/')

## deprecated

SERVICES = (
    'spicy.core.profile.services.ProfileService',
    'spicy.core.trash.services.TrashService',
    'spicy.mediacenter.services.MediaService',
    'spicy.mediacenter.services.LibraryService',
    'spicy.history.services.HistoryService',
    'spicy.xtag.services.TagService',
    'spicy.ratings.services.RatingService',
)

LOCALE_PATHS = (os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'locale'), )

#TEST_RUNNER = 'django_nose.runner.NoseTestSuiteRunner'
#NOSE_ARGS = ['-v', '--with-color']

ROOT_URLCONF = 'apps.urls'

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'spicy.core.siteskin.loaders.ThemeStaticFinder',
    'spicy.core.siteskin.loaders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',                                                                                                                                                             
)

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'spicy.core.siteskin.loaders.ThemeTemplateLoader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    'spicy.core.siteskin.loaders.BackendTemplateLoader',
)

template.add_to_builtins('django.templatetags.i18n')


TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',

    'spicy.core.profile.context_processors.auth',
    'spicy.core.siteskin.context_processors.base',
    'spicy.core.admin.context_processors.base',

    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',

    'apps.webapp.context_processors.site_content',
    )

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    #'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware', - don't use it =)
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',

    'spicy.core.profile.middleware.AuthMiddleware',

    'django.middleware.doc.XViewMiddleware',

    # XXX is it required ??
    'spicy.core.siteskin.middleware.AjaxMiddleware',
    'spicy.core.siteskin.threadlocals.ThreadLocals',
)

if DEBUG:
    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES += (
        # for developers
        'spicy.core.rmanager.middleware.ProfileMiddleware',
    )


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # Django admin
    'django.contrib.admin',

    # Django native apps
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # Application
    'apps.webapp',

    # Spicy core components
    'spicy.core.admin',
    'spicy.core.service',
    'spicy.core.siteskin',
    'spicy.core.simplepages',

    # Spicy apps
    'spicy.presscenter',
    'spicy.categories',
    'spicy.mediacenter',
    'spicy.core.profile',
    'spicy.feedback',
#    'spicy.labels',
    'spicy.seo',
    'spicy.xtag',

    # 'django_nose',
    # 'captcha',
    'sorl.thumbnail',
    'pytils',
    'raven.contrib.django.raven_compat',
]

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging                                                                                                                                                                 
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to                                                                                                                                                                    
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.                                                                                                                                                                 
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for                                                                                                                                                               
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.                                                                                                                                                              
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'common': {
            'format': '[%(asctime)s][%(levelname)-9s] %(name)s %(filename)s:%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d | %(message)s',
            'datefmt': '%H:%M:%S',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'null': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.NullHandler',
        },
        'console':{
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'common'
        },
        # 'sentry': {
        #     'level': 'INFO',
        #     'class': 'raven.handlers.logging.SentryHandler',
        #     'dsn': '{{ spicy.config.sentry }}',
        # }
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level': 'INFO',
        },
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level': 'INFO',
        },
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': False,
        },
    }
}



# App custom models

#CUSTOM_USER_MODEL = ''
CUSTOM_DOCUMENT_MODEL = 'webapp.Document'
#LABELS_CONSUMER = CUSTOM_DOCUMENT_MODEL

#CUSTOM_MEDIA_MODEL = 'blog.BlogMedia'
#CUSTOM_MEDIA_PROVIDER_MODEL = 'blog.BlogMediaProvider'
```

And manage.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                                                                                                                                                                                 
import os, sys
from importlib import import_module

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", 'apps.settings')

from django.conf import settings
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Outer urls.py (./apps/urls.py):

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import include, patterns, url
from django.conf import settings
from spicy import utils

from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

handler404 = 'spicy.core.siteskin.views.page_not_found'
handler500 = 'spicy.core.siteskin.views.server_error'
handler403 = 'spicy.core.siteskin.views.forbidden'

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^django/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('spicy.core.admin.urls', namespace='spicyadmin')),
    url(r'^captcha/', include('captcha.urls')),
    )
```

Inner urls.py (./apps/webapp/urls.py):

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

public_urls = patterns(
    '',
    )

public_urls += patterns(
    url(r'^create/$', 'create_article', name='create'),
    url(r'^a(?P<doc_id>\d+)/$', 'document', name='doc'),
    url(r'^a(?P<doc_id>\d+)/edit/$', 'edit_article', name='edit'),
    )

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^', include(public_urls, namespace='public'))
    )
```

What may be the reason of that exception? I have tried all that I found in stackoverflow. I guess the reason may be in wrong references to settings.py or ROOT_URLCONF, I have tried various choices but I am still getting the Attribute error.

And also I guess that the reason could be in middleware which may redefine ROOT_URLCONF while the server is performing a request (because it is ok before I wouldn't make any request to server), but I don't know where I can fix it.

Am I right in my guesses? And if yes, how can I solve my problem? Hope for any help!

Comment: Can you show `settings.py` file (without `SECRET_KEY`)?

Comment: @VladimirDanilov, settings.py added.

Comment: Update default project layout in Django 1.4 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.4/#updated-default-project-layout-and-manage-py

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have to register your app (Apparently called "apps") to your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Also, you are setting `apps.urls` in your `ROOT_URLCONF`, but setting just `urls` (without the `apps.` part) on your environmental values

Comment: I fixed that - changed environmental value ROOT_URLCONF to apps.urls. Now it is like ROOT_URLCONF in settings.py. But I still have an error.

Comment: Thanks for all comments. 
The reason of error was my trouble. I configured environment wrong.